# What is the security of Powershell "TrustedHosts"? (is it just a name match)?

Tags: windows, firewalls, configuration, powershell, windows-server

Powershell has a [TrustedHost](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx) section that is configured like this:

```
 winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="CorpServer56"}'
```

What security is implied for CorpServer56?  Is it just an ASCII name match on the host that is "trusted"?

I'm concerned about someone guessing a trusted host, and faking that name in order to gain access to a computer.